# Find the equation of the plane tangent to the graph $ \ f(x,y) \ $ at $ \ P(-1,1) \ $.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let  $ \ \ f(x,y)=\int_{x^2}^{y} e^{-t^2} dt \ $ and  let  $ \ P=(-1,1) \ $ be a point on the graph $ \ f(x,y) \ $.

Find the equation of the plane tangent to the graph $ \ f(x,y) \ $ at $ \ P(-1,1) \ $.

**Answer**

I tried to find the expression of $ f(x,y) \ $  directly  but I got

$ f(x,y)=\int_{y}^{x^2} e^{-t^2}dt =[\frac{\sqrt \pi erf(t)}{2}]_{x^2}^{y} \ =\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2} [erf (y)-erf (x^2) ] $,

where $ \ erf(t) \ $ is the **Gauss error function.**

**Then how to find the tangent at $ P(-1,1) \ $** .

**Is there any help ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to actually know the error function to do this problem. Note that $$\nabla f(x, y) = (-2xe^{-x^4}, e^{-y^2})$$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Then, $$\nabla f(-1, 1) = (2/e, 1/e)$$ which, along with the fact that $f(-1, 1) = 0$, tells us that the tangent plane will be $z = \frac{2}{e}x+\frac{1}{e}y+\frac{1}{e}$, which could equivalently be expressed as $$2x+y-ez = -1$$

Comment: yes it is correct

Answer (score 2):

For beginners let me rewrite Michael's solution a bit:

$z = f(x,y)$  passes through $P'(-1,1)$ ,

$z = f(-1,1) = 0$,. hence  $P(-1,1,0)$.

$F(x,y,z) := z - f(x,y) = 0$.

Find normal plane to $F(x,y,z) = 0$ at $P(-1,1,0)$.

$\nabla F(x,y, z) =   (2xe^{-x^4},- e^{-y^2}, 1)$.

At the point $P(-1,1,0)$:

$\vec n := \nabla F(-1,1,0) = $

$(-2/e, -1/e, 1)$, where

$\vec n$ is the normal of  the plane.

Equation:

$ \vec n \cdot ( \vec r - (-1,1,0)) = 0$, or

$(-2/e)x - (1/e)y + z - 1/e =0$,

$2x + y - e z = -1$.

Comments welcome.